# Give an example to show that ∀ does not distribute over ∨

Tags: calculus, logic

$$\forall x \in X, p(x) \lor q(x) \iff \forall x \in X, p(x) \lor \forall x \in X, q(x)$$

Give an example to show this is False.

I might have these types of questions on tests, so I want to know what is the $simplest$ example one can give about this

Comment: Every number is either even or odd.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Great minds ...

Comment: P (x) is true and q (x) is false, like "0=0" and its negation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite know what would be considered the 'Simplest', but a 'simple' one would be to consider p(x): x is an even number and q(x) : x is an odd number, assuming X: natural numbers

Comment: Maybe a simple one could be something like, heres a set, {0,1}, p(0) is True, p(1) is False, something like thiat

Comment: @KracX Yeah, I was thinking that too ... but it would maybe not be the most intuitive one.  I think the even and odd example one can grasp immediately

Comment: can u tell me what u were thinking? the set way? cuz the even and odd is always not the best